# In NLog, is it possible to use layouts to define the log level?

Tags: c#, logging, nlog

I would like to use [Layouts](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Layouts) in NLog to be able to change the minimum log level using an external variable :

```
<nlog>
   <variable name="loglevel" value="Debug"/>
   <targets>
      <target ... /> 
   </targets>
   <rules>
      <logger name="*" minlevel="${loglevel}" writeTo="LogFile" />
   </rules>
</nlog>
```

After starting NLog, all log levels (eg : Tracing, Debug, Info, ...) are set to `false` which indicate NLog failed to parse `minlevel` attribute properly.

The NLog layout feature seems to works with `target` attributes only.
What I want to achieve : in my real app, loglevel is not a constant but rather a custom [layout renderer](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Layout-renderers).

I have also tried to replace `value="Debug"` by `value="LogLevel.Debug"` without success.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47475698/how-to-control-nlog-loglevel-using-environment-variables

Answer (score 0):

### ** Updated Answer **

NLog ver. 4.6 added support for using NLog-Config-Variables in minLevel. See https://github.com/NLog/NLog/pull/2709

NLog ver. 4.6.7 added support for adjusting minLevel at runtime, by modifying NLog-Config-Variables and calling `ReconfigExistingLoggers()`. See https://github.com/NLog/NLog/pull/3184

### ** Original Answer **

The `minlevel`, `maxlevel` and `level` attributes on `<logger>` should be fixed strings.

In this case you could use a `<filter>`, e.g.

```
<nlog>
   <variable name="loglevel" value="Debug"/>
   <targets>
      <target ... /> 
   </targets>
   <rules>
      <logger name="*" writeTo="LogFile" >
          <filter condition="${level} >= ${loglevel}" action="Log">
      </logger>
   </rules>
</nlog>
```

See the [docs](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/When-filter)

Comment: The filter condition works but only if defined as a constant eg : `level >= LogLevel.Debug`. I was not able to make it work as a variable : `level >= ${loglevel}`. Also the syntax to use seems to be slightly different syntax than yours, see here : https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Conditions